# Evaluate bluebird promise to resolved value

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

If I have a function that returns a promise, how do I evaluate it to it's return value?

```
function fun () {
  return new Promise (function (resolve, reject) {
    resolve("test");
  });
}
var x = fun();
```

How do I get "test" out of x?
I just get an [object Promise].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do this

```
x.then(function(v) { 
    console.log(v); 
});
```

you'll see that v is "test"

Read all about promises - [Promise/A+](https://promisesaplus.com/) and [PromiseJS.org](https://www.promisejs.org/)

Comment: For OP, [JavaScript Promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/) is another topic that worth to read.

Comment: Is there a reason there is no way to extract this value? It seem kinda inconvenient. I know that this is the way promises do their stuff, but it should be easy for e.g. bluebird to add an extract method. But they didn't which means it's not considered good code? If yes, why not?